# C# Razor Syntax inside a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

This is the Code I'm having problems with:

```
@{int i = 1;}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @:<ul id="sortablei" class='droptrue'>
    i++;
}
```

How can I use i in the id sortablei?
I tried: @i or @{i} but it seems without a space before the i its not working.
I couldn't find an answer to my problem in the Razor Syntax Reference so I'm a bit clueless right now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Brackets:

```
@:<ul id="sortable@(i)" class='droptrue'>
```

The brackets here scope the razor expression; in many cases they aren't required, however they are necessary when:

- the expression (on the right) is non-trivial (spaces. etc) and needs help to scope it
- where without it, it looks like an email address, i.e. `abc@def` - this has special handling to avoid breaking pages with email addresses in them

Comment: Ahh so simple, yet it wasn't mentioned in the reference! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
@model System.Generic.Collections.List<MyNameSpace.Product>
@{
    int i = 1;
    string sortablei = "abc",
           droptrue = "abc-cls";
}

<ul id="@sortablei" class="@droptrue">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       <li>@item.Qty x @item.Name</li>
       i++;
    }
</ul>
```

Here's a [quick reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) for your knowledge.

---

Seams like I didn't got it right,

as Mark said, all you need to do is surround the variable with brackets like

```
sortable@(i)
```

I hope the reference is somewhat useful, as your particular problem can be found in **Explicit Expression** example